# Gnome: Prevent turning off screen when locked

Tags: gnome, 17.10, lock-screen, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 with gnome shell, and want my monitors to stay alive when screen gets locked.

*Background: It's a Notebook connected to external monitors which need ages to wake after every time they get black. Locking is necessary and needs to happen after an idle time and manually, so Caffeine is no option.*

Any hints on how to achieve that behavior? Possibly an extension?

Comment: I noticed that if I move my cursor just before it dims out, just after activating lock-screen, then it stays on according to my brightness and lock setting. Ubuntu 17.10.