# Disabling Lock Screen Fade to Black on Ubuntu 17.10 (Wayland)

Tags: 17.10, screen, lock, wayland

When I lock the screen with the shortcut or 
    gnome-screensaver-command -l

The screen locks then sleeps, putting my monitor to sleep, I can't seem to be able to make any xorg workarounds work in Wayland (Obviously)

Is there a way to disable this functionality? It is really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

This is from another [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978153/gnome-prevent-turning-off-screen-when-locked/1002352#1002352) I posted where OP has yet to log into Ask Ubuntu again to respond. To set these options open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. The changes take effect for the current session and permanently.

### For Login screen:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
```

### Disable dimming screen when idle:

In [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257329/laptop-screen-dims-after-20-seconds-cannot-change-that/258886) someone complained when on battery screen dims every 20 seconds and wants to turn that feature off:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim false
```

Comment: This is fairly old but I am searching for a similar issue -- the first above (idle-activation-enabled = false) does not seem to work on wayland in 18.10.  It does in X11. This is a bit off topic as the OP wanted the fade to black off, and I am speaking specifically of the screen saver when idle.

Comment: @Linwood If it's wayland related you are better off posting a new question because it's a different can of worms than X11 which most Q&A target.

Comment: Thanks, I have a question outstanding, I was just noting for the OP there were related issues.  If it is helpful to anyone who arrives here, this is the link to lack of ability to turn off screen saver (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2404301), and this to a wayland vs X11 issue with touch screens (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476576/disable-device-removed-from-touchscreen-hid-on-ubuntu-18-10) that might force people to choose wayland if they are touchscreen only.  If anyone can help with those I suggest doing it there.